# How do I test input type in jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, input-type-file

In a form I wanted to test if I have two input which is number type , two input which is text and one which is checkbox. How do i use `find()`(or other method) method to get input type to compare?

Seems like I found a way,

```
 const wrapper = shallow(<Login/>);
    const type = wrapper.find('input').map((node) =>node.props().type);
    const phone = type.filter((e)=>e === 'number').length===1;
    const password = type.filter((e)=>e === 'password').length===1;
    const checkbox = type.filter((e)=>e === 'checkbox').length===2;
    expect(phone).toBeTruthy();
    expect(password).toBeTruthy();
    expect(checkbox).toBeTruthy();
```

Still is there any better way?